# Where is my memory? -- LibraryLink never returns the memory

Tags: bugs, memory, librarylink

**Bug introduced in 8.0 or earlier and persisting through 10.3**

---

This is an example LibaryLink code from Mathematica [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/LibraryLink/tutorial/InteractionWithMathematica.html), which takes an integer and return an integer list:

```
 $HistoryLength = 0;    
 Needs["CCompilerDriver`"];

 MMASrc = "
   #include \"WolframLibrary.h\"
   #include \"WolframCompileLibrary.h\"

   DLLEXPORT int demo_I_T(WolframLibraryData libData, 
              mint Argc, MArgument *Args, MArgument Res) {
      MTensor T0;
      mint i, I0, dims[1];
      int err = LIBRARY_NO_ERROR;

      I0 = MArgument_getInteger(Args[0]);
      dims[0] = I0;

      err = libData->MTensor_new(MType_Integer, 1, dims, &T0);
      for ( i = 1; i <= I0 && !err; i++) {
          err = libData->MTensor_setInteger( T0, &i, i*2);
      }
      MArgument_setMTensor(Res, T0);
      return err;
  }
  ";

CreateLibrary[MMASrc, "mylib", "TargetDirectory" -> "/tmp"];   
libFunc = LibraryFunctionLoad["/tmp/mylib.dylib", "demo_I_T", {Integer}, {Integer, 1}];
```

The library function never returns the memory :

```
Table[Table[libFunc[100], {40000}]; Pause[0.1]; MemoryInUse[]/1024.^2, {10}]
(* {66.3692, 100.548, 134.727, 168.906, 203.085, 237.264, 271.443, 305.622, 339.8, 373.979} *)
```

compared to Mathematica function:

```
mmaFunc[i_] := 2*Range[i]

Table[Table[mmaFunc[100], {40000}]; Pause[0.1]; MemoryInUse[]/1024.^2, {10}]
(* {373.984, 373.984, 373.984, 373.984, 373.984, 373.984, 373.984, 373.984, 373.984, 373.984} *)
```

Why and how to fix it?

---

A different facet of the same bug is described [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29735/12).

Comment: By "returns the memory", do you mean "frees the memory" -- that is, returns it to the system to be reused?  As opposed to the function returns no value?

Comment: @MichaelE2 yes I mean frees the memory to the system.

Comment: added [tag:bugs] per [ruebenko](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29616/52).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is not an issue with `LibraryLink` as such. It seems to be an issue with how the compiled function interpreter calls a library link function. It's a bug and submitted as such.
If you replace your code with

```
Table[Table[libFunc[100];, {40000}]; Pause[0.1]; 
 MemoryInUse[]/1024.^2, {10}]
```

there is no memory leak. Note the `;` after the call to `libFunc[100]`.

Comment: Could you explain more about your code and why it gives a different memory usage? And also why I don't need the ; in the mathematica version? Thanks.

Comment: @xslittlegrass, I do not know why the `;` is necessary but I'll try to find out. Should I find something I'll report it here.

Comment: @xslittlegrass, please note the update.